Finding which element of shapely geometry satisfies a predicate
I'm looking for an element of a geometry, which satisfies a predicate, e.g. intersection. Here is a code snippet:
from shapely import *

p0 = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 4), (4, 4), (4, 0), (0, 0)])
p1 = Polygon([(6, 6), (6, 9), (9, 9), (9, 6), (6, 6)])
p2 = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)])
mp = MultiPolygon([p0, p1])

I would like to find indices i of mp components, for which intersects(p2, get_geometry(mp, i)) is true. Are there functions in Shapely to accomplish it, or it is just more practical to use a list of Polygon and iterate through it?

I think you would need to iterate through the list of polygons either way

@IanTurton I can test for intersection with the whole MultiPolygon, but can't get indices of intersecting components.

A multipolygon is one geometry and if one component of a  multipolygon intersects with the reference geometry then the whole geometry intersects. If I were to write an algorithm I would make it to return true after finding the first intersection and if p1 intersects, p2 may intersect as well but my algorithm would not tell it. I guess that the existing algorithms work this way and the way to go is to explode the multipolygon and iterate through the polygons. Spatial index can make is faster if the multipolygon has very many parts.

You can use a Geopandas GeoDataFrame instead of a a MultiPolygon
(see Remove the intersecting parts in a set of polygons [closed])
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"id":["p0","p1","p2"],"geometry":[p0,p1,p2]})
print(gdf)
   id                      geometry
0  p0  POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 4.00000, 4....
1  p1  POLYGON ((6.00000 6.00000, 6.00000 9.00000, 9....
2  p2  POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 2.00000, 2....


With Geopandas alone:
heads, tails = gdf.sindex.query_bulk(gdf.geometry, predicate="intersects")
ix = heads != tails
heads = heads[ix]
tails = tails[ix]
print(list(zip(heads, tails))[0])
(0, 2) # the polygons p0,p2 intersects
print(gdf.loc[[0, 2], :])
   id         geometry
0  p0   POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 4.00000, 4....
2  p2   POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 2.00000, 2....

With pysal/libpysal:
import libpysal
W = libpysal.weights.fuzzy_contiguity(gdf,predicate='intersects')
gdf['inters']= W.component_labels
print(gdf)
   id                     geometry                         inters
0  p0  POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 4.00000, 4....      0
1  p1  POLYGON ((6.00000 6.00000, 6.00000 9.00000, 9....      1
2  p2  POLYGON ((0.00000 0.00000, 0.00000 2.00000, 2....      0

The polygons p0 and p2 intersects
